# How to download a website and put into another folder? java

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I have this java code that download the .xml from my website and save it as an .xmlfile.

My problem is i want to save it into another folder.

When i run the code it downloads the file and saves it to the same folder where the java code is located.

I have searched about this and i cant find anything. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class dlxml {
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   throws Exception {
      URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/lab/lab.xml");
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
      (new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
      BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter
      (new FileWriter("data.xml"));
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
         writer.write(line);
         writer.newLine();
      }
      reader.close();
      writer.close();
   }
}
```

So basically i want to download the file and save it to another folder. Is it possible?
and what if when i save it to a folder and there is the same file and name but i want to save it the same. For example i have data.xml save it to another folder but there is another same file with data.xml but i dont want it to be data(1).xml i want it to be data.xml
Thanks

Comment: Please Change your question title.

Comment: As youknow When you specify data.xml if it puts in your root folder you yourself can answer this question

Answer (score 2):

Just define the folder path while writing to the file. As shown below:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("\path\to\folder\data.xml"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FULL_PATH));
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code segment, you will want to change the file to use a path.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.xml"));
```

By just using the name of the file, it will create the file in the relative directory (the same folder your code is running from) You'll want to change it to an absolute path so you can specify where you're storing it.